# Reading Keys Exchanged By Services in Unix

Tags: java, cryptography

So we have 2 custom services on on certain ports in our Linux machine, that exchange a key based on a well known protocol.

> Is there a way (using Java) by which I can read the key exchanged by
>   these 2 services and exploit them using a known vulnerability?

I am looking at the Diffie-Hellman exchange protocol here, btw.

Is it even possible with Java? Or should I use Python or something else?

**EDIT:** I know how to do it in Windows and C#, but I am stuck with Linux and Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`KeyAgreement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.html) for Java's DH implementation, and [`Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) for creating a MitM between the client and server (assuming that's how you intend to exploit the vulnerability).